# manipulate ruby hashes to generate data series

Tags: ruby, chartkick, ruby-hash

I have hash from code like this below

```
{"Jan 2016"=>4649, "Feb 2016"=>3945, "Mar 2016"=>4870, "Apr 2016"=>4872,
"May 2016"=>6494, "Jun 2016"=>4981, "Jul 2016"=>9949, "Aug 2016"=>4842,
"Sep 2016"=>5820, "Oct 2016"=>4934, "Nov 2016"=>4136, "Dec 2016"=>8856,
"Jan 2017"=>3762, "Feb 2017"=>3261, "Mar 2017"=>2185, "Apr 2017"=>702}
```

this hash generated from code

```
@bookings.group_by_month(:check_in_date, format: "%b %Y").sum(:total_night)
```

I'm using this code to generate chart with chartkick, **I would like to group it quarterly** to generate data series so I can give each series with different color,

Expected output is

```
[
  {name: "Q1",data: {"Jan 2016"=>4649, "Feb 2016"=>3945, "Mar 2016"=>4870}},
  {name: "Q2",data: {"Apr 2016"=>4872, "May 2016"=>6494, "Jun 2016"=>4981}}
  …
]
```

Comment: Got it ! `{name: "Q1",data: {"Jan 2016"=>4649, "Feb 2016"=>3945, "Mar 2016"=>4870}}` is this good for you?

Comment: ya it's ok Q5, since I just use it to change color

Comment: Why you do not do it? Is there any problem?

Comment: I would like to know how I modify my code @bookings.group_by_month(:check_in_date, format: "%b %Y").sum(:total_night) , not using sample data that I wrote it,

Comment: Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, "[mcve]" and "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)". We'd like to see evidence of your effort. What did you try? Did you search and not find anything? Did you find stuff but it didn't help? Did you try writing code? If not, why? If so, what is the smallest code example that shows what you tried and why didn't it work? Without that it looks like you didn't try and want us to write it for you.

Comment: thank you for suggestion and link, will try to do better for next question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a.group_by { |k, v| [Date.parse(k).year, ((Date.parse(k).month - 1) / 3) + 1] }
 .map { |k, v| { quarter: k, data: v.to_h} }
# [
#   {:quarter=>[2016, 1], :data=>{"Jan 2016"=>4649, "Feb 2016"=>3945, "Mar 2016"=>4870}},
#   {:quarter=>[2016, 2], :data=>{"Apr 2016"=>4872, "May 2016"=>6494, "Jun 2016"=>4981}},
#   {:quarter=>[2016, 3], :data=>{"Jul 2016"=>9949, "Aug 2016"=>4842, "Sep 2016"=>5820}},
#   {:quarter=>[2016, 4], :data=>{"Oct 2016"=>4934, "Nov 2016"=>4136, "Dec 2016"=>8856}},
#   {:quarter=>[2017, 1], :data=>{"Jan 2017"=>3762, "Feb 2017"=>3261, "Mar 2017"=>2185}},
#   {:quarter=>[2017, 2], :data=>{"Apr 2017"=>702}}
# ]
```

Comment: thank you for complete code, especially the second line

Answer (score 2):

Assuming, all the months’ data is there:

```
input.each_slice(3)
     .map
     .with_index(1) { |a, i| { name: "Q#{i}", data: a.to_h } }
```

Comment: Nice solution! :)